# Nested styled component with nth-of-type

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Recently play with styled components and trying to mix it with `nth-of-type(1)` but encountering a difficulty. From what I understand `nth-of-type(1)`, it means to select the first related tag of its parent.

What I want to do is to select the first `SectionWrapper` in `SPageWrapper` but it doesn't take effect. There is no error.

Thank you very much in advance ! !

```
//page.js
import { PageWrapper } from "@pages/pageWrapper";

const Page = () => {
   return (
        <SPageWrapper>
            <DecoratedBackgroundImage/>
            <SectionWrapper>
                //first section wrapper
            </SectionWrapper>
            <SectionWrapper>
                 //second section wrapper
            </SectionWrapper>
        </SPageWrapper>
    );
}
```

```
//styled-component css

const SectionWrapper = styled.div`
    // other css
    align-items: center;
`;

const SPageWrapper = styled(PageWrapper)`
    ${SectionWrapper}:nth-of-type(1){
        align-items: flex-start;
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because `${SectionWrapper}` produces **class name** and not a **tag** in output styles (`nth-of-type` works with tags).

One possible solution would be styling `SectionWrapper` with `align-items: flex-start;` and overriding adjacent siblings:

```
const SPageWrapper = styled(PageWrapper)`
    ${SectionWrapper} {
        align-items: flex-start;
        
        & + & {
            align-items: stretch;
        }
    }
`;
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for pointing out that ! ! ! If this is the case, it is ok to use ```nth-child``` instead? I am planning to use ```> ${SectionWrapper}:nth-child(2) {
        align-items: flex-start;
    }``` but I wondering if the structure has changed. I may need to change the css every single time.

Comment: Yes you're right. Other option would be defining SectionWrapper as section instead of div. So you get semantic html and "of type" selectors would also work